# How do you pronounce "f/4.5"?

Tags: reading-aloud

How do you pronounce the part in bold?

> The camera has a 32mm lens with a maximum aperture of **f/4.5**.

Comment: It's so much easier if it's written as F4.5. f/4.5 is actually f=1/4.5. I guess this is why the big F notation was invented.

Comment: It's not 1/4.5, it's focal length over 4.5 eg 32/4.5. Usually written with an italic [or latin small f with hook] ƒ or lower case f where italics are not available. Lenses are usually actually inscribed like a ratio, eg 1:4.5 rather than f/4.5 used in magazines/reviews etc. I have never seen capital F used in any authoritative reference.

Comment: I've since discovered Canon use F4.5. I shoot Nikon who use f/4.5 in 'print' or 1:4.5 on the lenses themselves, so I'd never seen this before.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is the "F stop" and this particular setting is called

> eff four point five

It actually means "aperture is focal length divided by 4.5" and is explained in [*Photography Life*](https://photographylife.com/f-stop).

This is the conventional pronunciation when talking about the "F stop" in photography.

If this was general mathematics or engineering, one would say

> eff over four point five

Comment: @gonefishin'again. The OP asks how it is pronounced. Similar is for example 'Catch-22'. No-one says "catch hyphen twenty two."

Comment: I've always pronounced the "over" but I'm not a photographer so I'm prepared to accept that people generally don't. However, it's not similar to not pronouncing a hyphen - the "over" *means* something (division) and omitting it changes the meaning. If I quote the electrical formula `I=V/R` as "I equals Vee Arr" (no over) then I've changed the equation to `I=VR` which is wrong.

Comment: @Rodney the 4.5 stop is the same setting whether or not you say 'over'. There are not two different settings, one as 4.5 and one as 1/4.5. Omitting the 'over' does not create any confusion, as there would be if you say VR instead of V/R. Again, OP asks what people *say*, not what is scientifically correct.

Comment: I have always heard *f/4.5* pronounced as this answer says. Eventually, if it's not clear from the context what I am saying, I could say *f stop* (which happens rarely), but I would never pronounce *over*.

Comment: (In the rare-to-nonexistent case where the entry pupil diameter actually was 4.5 times the focal length, instead of 1/4.5 times, this would be called "f/0.22", pronounced "eff zero point two two". But I've never heard of a production lens with an f-number below f/0.9.)

Comment: @hobbs I don't know if 10 lenses are enough for a "production lens", but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Zeiss_Planar_50mm_f/0.7 is among the fastest lenses in history. Used by NASA for the dark side of the moon, and by Kubrick for shooting candlelight scenes in Barry Lindon.

Comment: Here's an example of a famous photographer (Joe McNally) talking about flash, shutter speed and f-stops : https://youtu.be/7G_CYoPgKHs?t=130 . He pronounces "f/16" as "eff sixteen", "f/2.8" as "eff two point eight" or simply "at two point eight".

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what you mean by `a maximum aperture`

If you mean "a maximum absolute aperture" then `eff over 4.5` is correct because `d=f/4.5` indeed, note the small "f" here stands for the focal length.

Or if you mean "a maximum relative aperture" then `eff 4.5` is correct, but should be written as "F4.5", note the big "F" and no slash.

Comment: Do you have citations for this? - it's something i've never seen before.

Comment: Hmm… Canon refers to their lenses as F4.5 rather than the f/4.5 adopted by Nikon et al. Starting to look like there's no single acceptable standard, just whichever a manufacturer prefers.